# missing permission on "billingAccounts/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX": billing.resourceAssociations.create Terraform (GCP)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I tried to automate the Shared VPC creation on GCP by using Terraform. I have enabled all the access to my service account (Org Admin, XpnAdmin, Storage Admin, Compute admin, Billing Admin)

But when i executed terraform apply it's throwing me following error:

> missing permission on "billingAccounts/CXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX": billing.resourceAssociations.create

I'm referring the Google provider [Github code](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/tree/master/examples/shared-vpc) for this demo.

Comment: `Billing Account Administrator` has the required permissions. This means that the service account that you are using with Terraform does not have the role `roles/billing.admin`.

Comment: I've run into the same issue and I have Billing Admin permissions.

Comment: Hey @john Hanley Thanks for your comment, Yup after i gave a billing admin access issue got resoled. Thanks a lot. May God Bless You:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite likely you have the billing admin, but you also need the ability to create billing assignments, or "Billing Project Manager".

https://cloud.google.com/billing/v1/how-tos/access-control

> billing.resourceAssociations.create AND resourcemanager.projects.createBillingAssignment on the Cloud Billing account.

There's some handy code to bootstrap a service account - [Google Project Factory](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-project-factory) - You might want to have a look at that. Once that SA is created you shouldn't have permissions issues

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now i resolved this issue by enabling the billing admin access to my SA. May God Bless You :)

Comment: @Ravi k I've the same error, could you please explain how did you solve this issue? How should I enableing the billing admin to my already exists SA?

Answer (score 5):

I was getting same error even my "Service Account" had the necessary "Organization" level permissions. Then I figured out, I need to give permission from "Billing Account". It worked.

I was following [this](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/managing-gcp-projects-with-terraform) tutorial to create projects via "Service Account" and "Terraform", but still was getting error. After some research, I followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/billing-access#update-cloud-billing-permissions) how-to and gave permission from "Billing Account".

*Project*, *Organization* and *Billing* are 3 separate components for permissions. Giving "Organization" level is not enough. The permission should be given from "Billing Account" as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when I had an old (deleted) billing account Id in my Terraform config.

<facePalm>Doh!</facePalm>

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. You can now assign the role to an identity with this `gcloud` CLI command (as of the time of writing is still on alpha):

```bash
gcloud alpha billing accounts add-iam-policy-binding 123456-ABCDEF-123ABD \
  --member "serviceAccount:youserviceaccount@projectID-of-the-serviceaccount.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
  --role="roles/billing.user"
```

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/billing/accounts/add-iam-policy-binding

Answer (score -1):

This error generally comes when you are logged into to machine/laptop and set default credentials to run terraform. Thereafter you got a new account or have been asked to use new account and you are authenticating using gcloud auth login / or gcloud auth application-default login. This will still use the previous account billing account. It is recommended to use Google CloudShell to run terraform script first time.